# Registry Write Privileges on Windows 7 with Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-7, uac

I was built an application on Delphi 7 + Windows XP Pro Sp3 platform, the application run correctly, than i sent this application to my friend that have a Windows 7 OS, my application cannot write the initialization data to the registry with an error "Failed to set data ...", i was suggesst my friend to right clik and choose "Run as Administrator...". How can i build my application on Delphi 7 that can run and write a registry on Windows 7?

Please help, because i could not find the right solution on google right now...

Thanks in advance...

Regards
Chrisna Obaja

Comment: You will find an automated solution in **[this](http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/f/80334?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20delphifeeds%20%28DelphiFeeds.com%29)** article.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should give a lot more detail in your question if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 6):

Modern versions of Windows have their users running without admin rights by default. This is controlled by UAC.

The solution is usually not to attempt to gain admin rights. Instead you should stop attempting things that need admin rights unless you really do need to. Typically only install programs need admin rights.

You don't say why you are writing to a restricted area of the registry but you should be able to find an alternative to doing so.

Comment: Actually, this answer is even less specific then rather unspecific question.

Comment: @user so should I just make up the details?

Comment: you need admin rights to do that even in xp. If you are sure that you have to write to a restricted area then add a requireAdministrator manifest to your app.

Comment: my app is run on admin account of w7 but i still can't write the registration data to HKLM with the above error. can you guide me to solve my problem in delphi 7. thank you

Comment: what do you mean by admin account. Be precise. A user in admin group?

Comment: did you run as admin? Do you know anything about UAC?

Comment: i just want to know how to write to HKLM with admin privileges on w7 like usually with double click to run the app because i don't want to use "run as" to run my app.

Answer (score 2):

You can only write without restriction in HKEY_CURRENT_USER section only - and that will almost be suficient.

To write other parts of registry make an installer.

Otherwise you need Administrator Rights or manifest file.